# Как использовать Github python-программисту новичку?

Tags: github

Я в одном статье читал что лучший способ изучение языка программирования это не книги и видеокурсы а чтение кода и написание кода. И лучший ресурс для чтение чужих кодов это Github. Я новичок ещё не пользовался Github-ом и не имею никакого представления. Я знаю Python в начальном уровне и хотел бы увеличить свой уровень читав чужих кодов. Не подскажите что мне делать ? Как использовать Github на пользу?

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=python&type=Repositories Ну как сказать. Надо ещё найти то, что Вам будет нужно..

Comment: @entithat По этой поисковой запрос можно найти программы сделанный на Python и всё что касается python-у?

Comment: слева в меню можете выбрать что Вас интересует.

Comment: @entithat спасибо ! :)